# Wordpress settings page options not updating backend

Tags: php, wordpress, settings, admin

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin, and I have been basing my admin page development off of the Codex's custom settings page [example](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/).  I have been unable to get it to update the setting in the wp_options db, and I can't seem to find a good explanation as to what I've done wrong.  When I click 'save settings', the page refreshes and a bar pops up at the top saying the settings were saved properly, but nothing shows up in wp_options, and the text input box isn't populated with the updated value.

Here's what I have:

Admin init section:

```
function secg_settings_init() {
    register_setting( 'secg', 'secg_options' );
    add_settings_section(
        'secg_section_developers',
        __( 'API Keys.', 'secg' ),
        'secg_section_developers_cb',
        'secg'
    );
    add_settings_field(
        'secg_field_test_secret_key', 
        __( 'test-secret-key', 'secg' ),
        'secg_field_test_secret_key_cb',
        'secg',
        'secg_section_developers',
        [
            'label_for' => 'secg_field_test_secret_key',
            'id' => 'test-secret-key'
        ]
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'secg_settings_init' );
```

Section and field Callbacks:

```
function secg_section_developers_cb( $args ) {
    ?>
    <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['id'] ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Section Developers Cb.', 'secg' ); ?></p>
    <?php
}

function secg_field_test_secret_key_cb( $args ) {
    $options = secg_option();
    ?>
    <input type="text" 
           name="secg_options[<?php echo esc_attr( $args['label_for'] ); ?>]" 
           id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['label_for'] ); ?>" 
           value="<?php $options[ $args['label_for'] ] ?>" />
    <?php
}
```

Add Page:

```
function secg_options_page() {
    add_menu_page(
    'My Plugin',
    'Plugin Options',
    'manage_options',
    'secg',
    'secg_options_page_html'
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'secg_options_page' );
```

Handler for setting default values:

```
function secg_option() {
    $default = array(
        'secg_field_test_secret_key' => 'test secret key'
    );
    return get_option('secg_options', $default);
}
```

And finally, the page itself:

```
function secg_options_page_html() {
   if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
      return;
   }

   if ( isset( $_GET['settings-updated'] ) ) {
       add_settings_error( 'secg_messages', 'secg_message', __( 'Settings Saved', 'secg' ), 'updated' );
   }

   settings_errors( 'secg_messages' );
   ?>
   <div class="wrap">
       <h1><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>
       <form action="options.php" method="post">
           <?php
           settings_fields( 'secg' );
           do_settings_sections( 'secg' );
           submit_button( 'Save Settings' );
           ?>
       </form>
   </div>
   <?php
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you physically checking the values in the database (eg via myphpadmin or similar)? If not, are you using any sort of object caching eg Memcach(d), opcache, apc??? These could be showing different values to those in the actual database.

Comment: I'm using myphpadmin to check the database